# mysql install libaudit_plugin.so report errors

Tags: mysql

system operate: cp

> /Users/xxx/Downloads/audit_plugin/lib/libaudit_plugin.so
> /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin msyql operate:install plugin audit soname
> "libaudit_plugin.so";  Error content：ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open
> shared library
>
> '/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/libaudit_plugin.so' (errno: 2
> dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/libaudit_plugin.so, 0x0002): tried:
> '/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/libaudit_plugin.so' (not a m)
>
> ```
> sudo xattr -C "libaudit_plugin.so"
> sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/libaudit_plugin.so
> ```